# Javascript document.getElementById multiple times on page

Tags: javascript

We create a script that gets the innerhtml of a element with specific class. This works perfect for the first `<table>`. But the script does not work for the second `<table>`.

I guess this is due to the getElementbyID. How can we edit our script, so it will work for each table?

HTML:

```
<table>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="image" rowspan="8">
            <div class="myedit" id="MyEdit"></div>
        </td>
        <td class="order" colspan="2">Text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="input-box">
                <ul id="options-183-list" class="options-list">
                    <li class="product-option active">
                        <span class="input-radio">
                            <input type="radio" class="radio  validate-one-required-by-name product-custom-option" onclick="opConfig.reloadPrice()" checked="" name="options[183]" id="options_183_2" value="591" price="0">
                        </span>
                        <label for="options_183_2">
                            <span class="option-name">Product option 1</span>
                            <span class="option-sku">SKU1</span>
                            <span class="price-notice default">€0</span>
                        </label>
                    </li>
                    <li class="product-option">
                        <span class="input-radio">
                            <input type="radio" class="radio  validate-one-required-by-name product-custom-option" onclick="opConfig.reloadPrice()" name="options[183]" id="options_182_2" value="590" price="0">
                        </span>
                        <label for="options_183_1">
                            <span class="option-name">Product option 2</span>
                            <span class="option-sku">SKU2</span>
                            <span class="price-notice default">€0</span>
                        </label>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<table>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="image" rowspan="8">
            <div class="myedit" id="MyEdit"></div>
        </td>
        <td class="order" colspan="2">Text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="input-box">
                <ul id="options-181-list" class="options-list">
                    <li class="product-option active">
                        <span class="input-radio">
                            <input type="radio" class="radio  validate-one-required-by-name product-custom-option" onclick="opConfig.reloadPrice()" checked="" name="options[181]" id="options_181_2" value="578" price="0">
                        </span>
                        <label for="options_181_2">
                            <span class="option-name">Product option 1</span>
                            <span class="option-sku">SKU1</span>
                            <span class="price-notice default">€0</span>
                        </label>
                    </li>
                    <li class="product-option">
                        <span class="input-radio">
                            <input type="radio" class="radio  validate-one-required-by-name product-custom-option" onclick="opConfig.reloadPrice()" name="options[181]" id="options_181_2" value="579" price="0">
                        </span>
                        <label for="options_181_1">
                            <span class="option-name">Product option 2</span>
                            <span class="option-sku">SKU2</span>
                            <span class="price-notice default">€0</span>
                        </label>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">     
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('input').click(function () {
            var sku = $('input:checked').closest('.product-option').find('.option-sku').html();
            document.getElementById("MyEdit").innerHTML = sku
        });
        var sku = $('input:checked').closest('.product-option').find('.option-sku').html();
            document.getElementById("MyEdit").innerHTML = sku
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You don't need `document.getElementById` if you are using jQuery. Why can't you use `$("#MyEdit").html(sku);` Why do you wanna mix two APIs?

Comment: ID must be **unique**.

Comment: And `Id`s must be unique

Comment: You shouldn't have multiple elements with the same (supposedly unique) `id`. How is the browser supposed to know which one you're referring to?

Comment: An ID has to be **unique** on the whole page. Take a look at `getElement` (singular). It returns only one element because it's supposed to find only one ID.

Comment: Tables shouldn't be used for layout, although forms can be tabular, the way you have done it, it should not be in a table

Comment: @Pete "Tables shouldn't be used for layout" - this brings back (bad) memories :D

Comment: hahaha, good to see another js question with every answer downvoted, well done

Comment: @Pete Yeah, but those answers are correct. If you need to select multiple elements, you should not select by ID but rather using a class name.

Comment: @feeela have you heard of sarcasm?  I am conveying my contempt at the js users as it only seems to be that tag where I regularly see correct answers being downvoted - the most toxic community on this site

Comment: @Pete Ah, yeah. Yes I heard of sarcasm, but is it herd to get the tone right in written communication ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is, you are not searching by class. You are searching by id. You should use document.querySelector('.myedit') to get all of the myedit elements. And to set the innerHTML you will need to loop through all of the results and set the content for each one of them. Something like:

```
for (var result in document.querySelectorAll('.myedit'))
{
result.innerHTML = sku;
}
```

Good luck! :)

Comment: That is not how `querySelector()` works

Comment: Yeah, I said "something like" if you read the answer.

Comment: I did read the answer and the code used would have thrown error

Comment: Nope, it wouldn't have. (hint: psuedocode does not have errors, you nitwit @charlietfl)

Answer (score 0):

You can assign id only to 1 element. What you need is to find them by class.
`document.querySelectorAll('.myedit')` is whay you need.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll

Note: that this returns multiple elements so you have to loop thru them

Update: I didn't notice that you are using jQuery as you are easiest would be:

```
$('.myedit').each(function(){
    $(this).html(sku)
})
```

Answer (score -1):

ID's must be unique. You can try `document.getElementsByClass()`. This will get you list of elements with that class.